# Rendering React Ajax with proper child access

Tags: ajax, reactjs, dataflow

I really don't see why one works and the other doesn't hoping someone can shed some rays of light.

That is:

```
*some component constructor 
this.state = { dataTransform: '' };

render(){
       if (this.state.dataTransform === ''){
          return null;
       }
       else {
          return ( <Chart config={this.state.dataTransform}/> );
       }       
}
```

**vs** 
https://facebook.github.io/react/blog/2014/07/17/react-v0.11.html#rendering-to-null 
no initialization of dataTransform or undefined

```
render(){
       if (!this.state.dataTransform){
          return null;
       }
       else {
          return ( <Chart config={this.state.dataTransform}/> );
        }       
}
```

This one will return error unable to read property of dataTransform of null until the request is done and the state is updated.Yet, the top one works with no problem no error messages while performing the get request.

Though the react example https://facebook.github.io/react/tips/initial-ajax.html
loads within the same component I want to remain stateless and let my parents do the work

Comment: Am I correct in assuming that you don't initialise state at all? - that won't work I'm afraid, in the react example this.state is defined and thats why it works - you cannot try to access a property of something thats undefined

Comment: The ajax example sure, but ideally these are the same. I'm not accessing it in the bottom unless it's defined yet the initial render errors until the request comes back, but to me it should just render null until then by the conditional render. The request is in componentDidMount() of course.

Comment: Bah!  I see... looking to hard at the wrong things for too long.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Passing Values via Props From React Stateless Child to Parent](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/37554657/passing-values-via-props-from-react-stateless-child-to-parent)