# Passing Values via Props From React Stateless Child to Parent

Tags: javascript, reactjs, ecmascript-6

**CONTEXT**

I'm trying to pass input value fields (`conditionTitle`) from a React Stateless child component (`AddConditionSelect`) to the parent component (`AddConditionDashboard`) that will hold my state.

**PROBLEM**

I followed the model shown in the [React documentation](http://facebook.github.io/react/docs/thinking-in-react.html), but they are using refs, which only works if the component is stateful. I do not want to have to set any state in the child component, but still be able to access the input in the parent.

In its current form, I am getting a Warning, that the stateless function components cannot be given refs, resulting in props being null and undefined.

Parent Component:

```
import AddConditionSelect from '../containers/AddConditionSelect.js';

class AddConditionDashboard extends React.Component {
  constructor(props) {
    super(props);

    this.state = {
      conditionTitle: '',
      conditionType: ''
    };
  }

  handleUserInput({conditionTitleInput}) {
    this.setState({
      conditionTitle:conditionTitle
    })

  }

  render() {
    const {error, segmentId} = this.props;

    return (
      <div>

    <AddConditionSelect segmentId={segmentId} conditionTitle={this.state.conditionTitle} onUserInput={this.handleUserInput} />


    <PanelFooter theme="default">
      <Button backgroundColor="primary" color="white" inverted={true} rounded={true} onClick={(event) => this.onSubmit(event)}>
        Next Step
      </Button>
    </PanelFooter>

      </div>
    );
  }

}

export default AddConditionDashboard;
```

Child component:

```
class AddConditionSelect extends React.Component {

  onInputChange: function() {
    this.props.onUserInput(
      this.refs.conditionTitleInput.value,
    )
  },

  render() {
    const {error} = this.props;

    return (
      <div>

        <Panel theme="info">

        <Divider />

        Please enter a name {error ? <Message inverted={true}  rounded={true}  theme="error">{error}</Message>  : null}
          <Input value={this.props.conditionTitle} ref="conditionTitleInput" label="" type="text" buttonLabel="Add Condition" name="add_segment" onChange={this.onInputChange} placeholder="Condition Title"/>

       </Panel>
     </div>
    );
  }

}
export default AddConditionSelect;
```

Comment: can you show us your Input component? That would help.

Comment: The input component is just a Rebass component - http://jxnblk.com/rebass/#Input

Answer (score 6, accepted):

How about passing the event handler directly to `<Input>`? This way you pass the on change event directly to your parent (grandparent of `<Input>`) and you can extract the value from `event.target.value` so no need to use refs:

*Note:* You might have to `bind` the context of `onUserInputChange()` in you parent's constructor because event handlers have the element on which the event happened as their context by default:

**Parent**

```
class AddConditionDashboard extends React.Component {

  constructor(props) {
    // ...

    // bind the context for the user input event handler
    // so we can use `this` to reference `AddConditionDashboard`
    this.onUserInputChange = this.onUserInputChange.bind(this);
  }

  onUserInputChange({ target }) {
    const { value: conditionTitle } = target;
    this.setState({
     conditionTitle
    });
  }

  render() {
    // ...

    <AddConditionSelect segmentId={segmentId} 
                        conditionTitle={this.state.conditionTitle} 
                        onUserInputChange={this.onUserInputChange} // <-- pass event handler to child that will pass it on to <Input>
    />

    // ...
  }
  // ...
```

**Child:**

```
class AddConditionSelect extends React.Component {

  render() {
    const { error } = this.props;

    return (
      <div>
        // ...

        <Input value={this.props.conditionTitle} 
               label="" 
               type="text" 
               buttonLabel="Add Condition" 
               name="add_segment" 
               onChange={this.props.onUserInputChange} // <-- Use the grandparent event handler
               placeholder="Condition Title"
        />

       // ...
     </div>
    );
  }
}
```

Comment: thank you for the super detailed answer! It's much more clear now. However, the child component with the input is now rendered correctly (no error), but I'm unable to populate the input field (no error in console though).I imagine that this has something to do with the two way binding that I was doing in the previous version of the child component...

Comment: @Dan No worries, glad to help :). Btw, what do you exactly mean by "I'm unable to populate the input field"?

Comment: Thanks :) Typing in the input field has no effect. After commenting out the part of my constructor that sets the state `this.state = { conditionTitle: '' }`, the input field can then be populated. However, console.logging inside `onUserInputChange()` has no effect - so it is like it the function does not fire on input change. :S

Comment: Try using the browser debugger to put a breakpoint inside `onUserInputChange` and make sure it's getting called. If not, then make sure `this.props.onUserInputChange` in child points to the parent function. If it does, make sure `onChange` inside the `<Input>` actually gets called. If you are getting the calls but the value isn't being updated, then make sure `onChange` actually passed the value back into the method and that `render` method of the child gets called with the updated `this.props.conditionTitle`. Just make sure everything links up properly from the top component to `<Input>` :)

Comment: Cheers! The debugging trace helped! I was forgetting to call props on the input element onChange. Thanks again :)

Answer (score 1):

1. You don't need ref. value can be extracted from the event. Thus, you children component becomes simpler.
2. You can simplify your code further using the [value link pattern](https://medium.com/@gaperton/managing-state-and-forms-with-react-part-1-12eacb647112#.c5k6o9uaf).

   class AddConditionDashboard extends React.Component {
     constructor(props) {
       super(props);

   ```
   this.state = {
     conditionTitle: '',
     conditionType: ''
   };
   ```

   }

   render() {
       const {error, segmentId} = this.props;

   ```
   return (
     <div>

       <AddConditionSelect segmentId={segmentId} conditionTitle={ Link.state( this, 'conditionTitle' ) } />


       <PanelFooter theme="default">
       <Button backgroundColor="primary" color="white" inverted={true} rounded={true} onClick={(event) => this.onSubmit(event)}>
           Next Step
       </Button>
       </PanelFooter>

     </div>
   );
   ```

   }

   }

   export default AddConditionDashboard;

And child component

```
const AddConditionSelect = ({ error, valueLink }) => (
    <div>

    <Panel theme="info">

    <Divider />

    Please enter a name { error ?
                            <Message inverted={true}  rounded={true}  theme="error">
                                {error}
                            </Message>  : null }
        <Input  value={ valueLink.value }
                onChange={ e => valueLink.set( e.target.value ) }
                label="" type="text"
                buttonLabel="Add Condition" name="add_segment" 
                placeholder="Condition Title"/>

    </Panel>
    </div>
);

export default AddConditionSelect;
```